# Different monitors causing Blue Prism region spying error

Tags: region, rpa, blueprism, spying

Here I am attempting to expand the DDL and select one of the options. I spied and built my BP application on my monitor and when testing on my laptop all the regions are slightly off. All elements spied in Browser mode are fine. In the region editor I have tried changing the Location Method to *Image* and the Position to *Anywhere*, which works when the using the monitor and the view has scrolled but unfortunately this does not resolve the region issues on my laptop. I have checked previous threads and I don't think zoom is the issue.

Highlighting the region when using my monitor:

[image]

Highlighting when on laptop:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is unfortunately a risk of the fragile Region spy mode.

Comment: @esqew thank you, I guess I'll have to try and find a way around this.

Comment: Anecdotally, this is why I personally **always** evaluate applications' compatibility with at least one of the more robust spy modes before committing to a Process build. Even when I've been able to get Region mode to work, it operates so slowly that it nukes most all of the potential value. You might also consider attempting automation of an API instead of continuing to wrangle with the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, fairly new to RPA so one of many learning curves! Do you have any indication as to why the question was marked down? Researched my topic and assumed I provided enough detail for replication, again, another one of those learning curves...

Comment: Completely honestly, I don't recall doing so but I must have added the downvote last night. I've reversed it as I don't think it's deserving of one - my apologies...

Comment: No worries, wasn't aware that it was you, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens for zoom settings on your browsers. Double check your zoom is set to 100% for both browsers.

Can confirm on my machines the zoom settings are different but then align when both set to 100% zoom.

Answer (score 1):

For using region mode we have to check the following things to make sure it works a correctly.

1. Screen resolution used while spying a region. Set the same **screen resolution** while running the process.
2. Use the **tolerance property 60%**.
3. If image is not visible on screen, use some static labels and spy them first through html mode. **Focus the label**, so that the region element gets visible in screen
4. Region mode elements takes time to identity. make sure to apply appropriate wait time.